# Word or short phrase similar to "self-centered" but not judgemental, condescending, or insulting

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am searching for a word or short phrase that is similar to "self-centered" but is not judgemental, condescending, or typically used as an insult.

I would like to use this word to describe a person that has the following qualities:

- Kind
- Generous
- Giving
- Loving
- Caring

But also *tends* to not regularly think about the needs of others.

I realize that this may seem to be incongruous or contradictory, but I actually know several people with all these qualities.

The best I've come up with so far is "self-focused", but to my ears, that still sounds judgemental and a bit like an insult.

Comment: I'm not sure there's an answer to this that can't be viewed as negative. The only solution would be if you could find a put a positive spin on it, like saying she's independent and doesn't care what others think of her. But that wouldn't mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: I agree with Stuart F. You could list the positive attributes and add a word, e.g., "She's kind, generous ... , although she tends to be/can be *self-absorbed*.

Comment: @StuartF and DjinTonic: I'm not sure either (hence my post), but I am hoping for at least a *neutral* word or phrase.  I hadn't thought of DjinTonic's suggestion of *self-absorbed*.  Taken literally, that initially seemed neutral, and I thought it might work.  But after a couple minutes of thought, it does seem a bit negative as well.  Hmmm...

Comment: Maybe a way to think about it is to assume *we* have all those qualities.  If so, how would *we* like someone to refer to us?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Indeed, the dictionary definitions were promising :-)  but I ditched an answer because almost all examples were in contrast to positive qualities. *Self-involved* redirects to *self-absorbed*.

Comment: navel gazing and navel gazer.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket it is a thought of as a negative quality, so most, if not all the words for it have a negative connotation. But having a negative quality neither negates your good qualities nor makes you a bad person, such a word is not necessary in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

"Introspective" means "turned inwards," and can have positive connotation. It could suggest focusing on one's self with a view toward improvement, or at least a dispassionate view, not just self-adulation.

Comment: In fact, it could be a great *euphemism* for self-centered, inserted into praise as a way of spinning a character flaw as a virtue.

Comment: I upvoted this because it is typically not seen as an insult, and is often used as a compliment.  It also provides some personal insight into how people with all these qualities perhaps perceive the world (and people) around them.  I'm not sure if it's exactly what I'm looking for, but it's at least on the right track.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeking an ameliorated version of ***tends** to be self-centred.*

Somewhat insular; may lack a broader view; can be solipsistic; shows some signs of adopting personally orientated solutions; would benefit from being less self-contained.

Fronting almost anything with "Occasionally..."; "Has shown a few instances of..." "Should look to improving ...", etc., may help.

Comment: [You are seeking x.]

Comment: @Lambie I'm not familiar with the meaning of your comment.  It was upvoted, so I'm guessing it's something specific to this SE.  Can you explain what you meant?

Comment: *Insular* is an interesting (and helpful) choice of words.  I upvoted because it is not a word typically used as an insult.  It has, IMO, a slightly negative connotation, but it's much closer to neutral than *self-centered*.

Comment: *Withdrawn* ? Perhaps if we know more about *why* the person doesn't think of others.

Comment: seek takes a direct object and without the pronoun for. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

**oblivious**

> Lacking active conscious knowledge or awareness  [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oblivious)

> Not aware of or not concerned about what is happening around one.
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/oblivious)

> Unaware or unconscious of. With of, to. (Now the usual sense.)
>
> *He was so little given to observation as to be frequently oblivious of what was passing around him.* OED

---

> My gift has always been to be more aware of the feelings of those
> around me than my generous but often **oblivious** spouse. [Darlene Porter; *Lives of Our Mothers*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Lives_of_Our_Mothers/37QtDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=generous%20but%20oblivious&pg=PT51&printsec=frontcover).

> Conversely, we all know lovable dolts who care deeply about others,
> but are **oblivious** to how their actions affect them. [D. C. Rose; *The Moral Foundation of Economic Behavior*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Moral_Foundation_of_Economic_Behavio/YJxpAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=caring%20but%20oblivious%20to%20others&pg=PA83&printsec=frontcover).

> The boy was utterly unconscious that he was treading on delicate
> ground as he rattled on his his warmhearted, frank and generous way.
> Totally **oblivious** that the very name of Ruthven must be unwelcome
> if not offensive to his listener, he... [R.W. Chambers; *The Younger
> Set*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Younger_Set/T-yPDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=warm%20hearted%20oblivious&pg=PT68&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: This goes in a bit of a different direction, and one I hadn't thought of.  Thanks.  It's too negative, but exposes a whole new direction of finding a good word or phrase, which is very helpful.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with what DjinTonic has said in comments.

**Self-absorbed** is the best non-judgmental word I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a perfect fit, but it might be good enough for what you are looking for:

["Flying by the seat of my pants"](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/fly-by-the-seat-of-your-pants.html) — ignoring predetermined plans or mechanics by his own initiative. Also using your own experience and trusting your own judgement to make a decision, ignoring other relevant helpful aids

*Adding in my comment to the description:*

The idea behind the idiom is to say that I am doing things as I please, regardless how others react and regardless of their instructions or opinions

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this could imply self-interest, like how someone flying by the seat of his pants is ignoring the needs of others?

Comment: @livresque The idea behind the idiom is to say that I am doing things as I please, regardless how others react and regardless of their instructions or opinions

Answer (score 0):

"Self-possessed" might be a good option.

Comment: Why would it be a good option? Please provide support for your choice, and a cited reference if possible. Simply suggesting a word without providing a convincing argument hardly constitutes a useful answer.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Sorry, new here. Self-possessed means in control of one's self, and synonyms range from self-assured to cool and composed. If your looking for a nice way to say self-centered (preoccupied with oneself), self-possessed is almost a mastery of oneself. But it could also be taken as a different word entirely, along the lines of cool and collected.